# PayPal Rest API - historical data

Tags: paypal

I'm just wondering if the new PayPal rest API can be used to receive historical data. For example getting a list of sales made before the rest API existed.

I thought there would be some way to hook it up but it seems you can only get sales that were made though the rest API itself.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct - only transactions created (via the REST API's) are returned in a `GET /payment` call today.
You would need to use the classic `TransactionSearch` API call for any transaction created prior to that.

Comment: thanks heaps! Don't happen to know if this intends to be changed in the future?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, but I haven't heard anything about it myself.